# How to define and iterate over map in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My knowledge of groovy doesn't go very far beyond what little I know about Jenkinsfiles. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have a map defined in a Jenkinsfile that can then be applied in a "for loop" fashion.

I have these variables:

```
mymap = {
    "k1": "v1"
    "k2": "v2"
    "k3": "v3" 
}
```

I have a `stage` in my Jenkinsfile that looks like this:

```
stage('Build Image') {
    withCredentials([[<the credentials>]) {
    sh "make build KEY={k1,k2,k3} VALUE='{v1,v2,v3}'"
}
```

Is there a way to make a `Build Image` stage for each of the pairings in `mymap`? I haven't had any luck with what I've tried.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are some similar [user-submitted examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-list) in the Jenkins documentation.

Something like this should work:

```
def data = [
  "k1": "v1",
  "k2": "v2",
  "k3": "v3",
]

// Create a compile job for each item in `data`
work = [:]
for (kv in mapToList(data)) {
  work[kv[0]] = createCompileJob(kv[0], kv[1])
}

// Execute each compile job in parallel
parallel work


def createCompileJob(k, v) {
  return {
    stage("Build image ${k}") { 
      // Allocate a node and workspace
      node {
        // withCredentials, etc.
        echo "sh make build KEY=${k} VALUE='${v}'"
      }
    }
  }
}

// Required due to JENKINS-27421
@NonCPS
List<List<?>> mapToList(Map map) {
  return map.collect { it ->
    [it.key, it.value]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Does this go in the global context? How does this fit into the `node {` context? I have this: ```node {
    try {
        checkout scm
            
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
```
and the stage comes after that.

Comment: Order doesn't really matter too much. Anything inside a `node` block gets executed on an agent somewhere. Your `checkout scm` block could also be in a `stage`, e.g. called 'Checkout', if you like.

Comment: This totally works. Thanks! The `createCompileJob`, the `data` defs and the `@NonCPS` blocks had to be put in the global section, and putting the `work = [:]` .... `parallel work` section in the `BRANCH_NAME` conditional did the trick.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine. However, the parallel build never finishes. Its keep running until aborted. Any idea?

Comment: How to execute work map in this example sequentially instead of parallel:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909155/1937596

Answer (score 13):

You can iterate over a map like this:

```
def map = [Io: 1, Europa: 2, Ganymed: 3]
for (element in map) {
    echo "${element.key} ${element.value}"
}
```

I don't know if a dynamic count of stages is useful. Maybe you could use parallel nodes, but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 8):

Since May 30, 2017 you can iterate over Maps without workarounds.
You need to upgrade Pipeline: Groovy plugin to >= 2.33
Related issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421

Plugin changelog: https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps

```
mymap = {
    "k1": "v1"
    "k2": "v2"
    "k3": "v3" 
}

for(element in mymap) {
    sh "make build KEY=${element.key} VALUE=${element.value}"
}
```

Comment: we have Pipeline: Groovy version 2.81 installed. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are have another simple way for  parse json  object  to groovy object - [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "myList": [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42] }')
println(object.myList)
```