# Running Jenkins parallel tasks sequentially

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a new Jenkins pipeline and have a set of steps that I would eventually like to run in parallel.  But while I'm developing this pipeline I'd like to force it to run sequentially.  I'm not seeing any way to specify the number of threads a parallel step uses or anything like that.  Here is the basic code so far:

```
node('x') {
    stage('cleanup'){
        def cleanupScripts = [:]
        cleanupScripts[1] = { sh(script: "cleanup1.sh") }
        cleanupScripts[2] = { sh(script: "cleanup2.sh") }
        cleanupScripts[3] = { sh(script: "cleanup3.sh") }
        cleanupScripts[4] = { sh(script: "cleanup4.sh") }
        parallel cleanupScripts
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to run those shell scripts sequentially without changing a lot of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `parallel cleanupScripts` you can use like this:

```
cleanupScripts.each{ key, value ->
    value()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to run parallel steps in jenkins. You can run parallel jobs  in the same node or in different nodes.

Running parallel jobs

```
parallel (
// job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
{ build("job1") },
{ build("job2") },
{ build("job3") }
)
```

You can make a job for each cleanup*.sh and call these jobs like above.

A more simple approach is use [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command

Or simplest

```
clenaup1.sh &! clenaup3.sh &! clenaup4.sh &! ...
```

Comment: Sorry, steps was a poor choice of variable name.  I'll change it.