# Jenkins scripted pipeline - sequential steps

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have this command in my scripted pipeline:

parallel map_of_stages

- map_of_stages is array of stages.

In this example - "parallel" is the "executing" 
But in case I need those stages to be run sequentially?

Is there an option of having something like "parallel" but for serial execution stages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"sequential" isn't a keyword you can use in Jenkins pipelines, but the steps are executed sequentially unless they are in a paralell block anyway, so you shouldn't need it.

This has some useful info:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages

Answer (score 0):

[source stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639498/running-jenkins-parallel-tasks-sequentially)

As found in another question:

```
map_of_stages.each{ key, value ->
    value()
}
```