# How to declare map in map variable in groovy and call it in jenkinsfile

Tags: dictionary, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, constants

I want to declare map variable in my constants.groovy for different kinds of environments:

1. TEST
2. PRE-PROD
3. PROD

and for each one I want to have its own URL and Jenkins user credential.
In the pipeline itself there will be a choice parameter where user will have to choose kind of environment.
Once build started, the pipeline will know how to pull the URL and Cred for the user choice. any idea how it can be done? As a start I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520071/11705021) can help

**UPDATE**

I got the answer for my question, but adding one on top of it:
How I can do `map` inside `map` here? assuming user chose `TEST`, I want it to have 3 types of server: `SQL`, `SSIS`, `SSRS`.
Is this the right code for it:

```
Map myMap = [
    TEST:[SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: ''], credential,
    PREPROD:[SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: ''], credential,
    PROD:[SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: ''], credential
    ] as ConfigObject
def props = myMap.toProperties()

props [ env.environment_type ].SQL_URL
props [ env.environment_type ].SSIS_URL
props [ env.environment_type ].credential
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but you can declare a map literal in Groovy like so:

```
Map myMap = [
    TEST:[ SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: '', credential:'' ],
    'PRE-PROD':[ SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: '', credential:'' ],
    PROD:[ SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: '', credential:'' ],
]
```

Notice the single quotes around `PRE-PROD`

Comment: Tnx. so the right use for it in my `jenkinsfile.groovy` would be for example:
`load("constants.groovy");myMap['env.environment_type'].url` right?

Comment: map key w/o quotes: `myMap[ env.environment_type ].url`

Comment: btw is `env.environment_type` of String-type?

Comment: it will be choice parameter, so yes, the values will be strings

Comment: I updated the question with one more query which I think is the right code. can you please approve?

Comment: almost right. you cannot leave `credentials` outside (compile error). A propper value would be `[SQL_URL:'', SSIS_URL: '', SSRS_URL: '',  credential:'' ],`

Comment: I see you didn't use `ConfigObject` in your answer. any specific reason why?

Comment: `myMap[ env.environment_type ].SQL_URL` can be called without ConfigObject

Comment: So is there any advantage for using `ConfigObject` in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what ConfigObject is. For the use-case you described in your question, the simple groovy map literal is absolutely sufficient.